# AppliciationUser в представлении asp.net-mvc visual studio 2017

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2017

Проблема в следующем: при создании представления, через контекстное меню(правой кнопкой, создать представления) на какой то из actions, в поле класс модели, не видно класс (`ApplicationUser`) а, класс (`ErrorViewModel`) который лежит рядом видно и если я убираю наследование(`: IdentityUser`) то его видно при создании представления в поле модель класса. Что за X@@нь такая???

В том же проекте на другом компьютере видно. В чём может быть проблема? Если кто сталкивался напишите, что можно сделать.

Comment: ничего не понятно - что и где и у кого видно? Не тратье попусту слова. приведите код, который не работает, код, которым вы решали проблему и что не получилось.

Comment: @tym32167 кода, много, да и не в этом суть. Проект работает нормально вот только на одном компе тыкаешь правой кнопкой на методе , добавит представление и в поле класс модели есть поле ApplicationUser ,а на другом компе нет. При чём даже если я создаю пустой проект asp.net.mvc , класса по прежнему нет. А, на другом компе есть.

Comment: А сам класс в коде присутствует? Иногда надо сбилдить проект, чтобы он появился в том диалоге

Comment: @tym32167 да присутствует, билдить тоже пробовал.

Comment: ну тогда это странно, но без возможности воспроизвести подсказать по сути нечего. Разве что студию переставьте :)

Comment: @tym32167 если хочешь ссылку на гитхаб могу дать по позже. Попробуешь.  Может что ещё выяснится.

Comment: @tym32167 в любом случае спасибо! Да и проект скидывать  не нужно. Просто новый проект создать можно asp net mvc с моделями и аутентификации и посмотреть.